# Javascript, Uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', "button", function (e) {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});
var filelist = new Array();

updateList = function () {
  var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
  var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

  var HTML = "<table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
      filelist[i] = input.files.item(i).name;
      HTML += "<tr><td>" + filelist[i] + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
  }

  HTML += "</table>";
  output.innerHTML = HTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2">
 <label class="label1">
  <img src="~/Images/upload.png" height="50px" width="50px" /> Upload Your File
  <input type="file" name="fileUploader" id="fileUploader" multiple onchange="javascript:updateList()" />
 </label>
</div>
<br />
```

In the code I am uploading multiple files. When I am trying to upload some more files the existing file list replaced with new list. Even after placing my array outside the function. 
[image]

Comment: Please share your html & also show who is calling `updateList` function

Comment: You replace the array elements by adding them with your index key that starts from zero: `filelist[i] = input.files.item(i).name;` instead of using something like `push`. It means that if your first selection has more files than your newest, the last files from the first selection are still in the array, am i right?

Comment: <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2">


                           <label class="label1">

                               <img src="~/Images/upload.png" height="50px" width="50px" /> Upload Your File
                               <input type="file" name="fileUploader" id="fileUploader" multiple onchange="javascript:updateList()" />

                           </label>
                           <br />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', "button", function (e) {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
    });
   </script>
   <script>
       var filelist = new Array();

       updateList = function () {
           var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
           var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

           var HTML = "<table>";
           for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
               filelist[i]=input.files.item(i).name;
               HTML += "<tr><td>" + filelist[i] + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
           }
           HTML += "</table>";
           output.innerHTML += HTML;
       }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the previously added file names, you should `push` the file names into `filelist`.

```js
var filelist = new Array();

updateList = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
    var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

    var HTML = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        //filelist[i] = input.files.item(i).name;
        filelist.push(input.files.item(i).name);
        HTML += "<tr><td>" 
              + filelist[i] 
              + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
    }
    HTML += "</table>";
    output.innerHTML = HTML;
    console.log(filelist);
}
```

```html
<input id="fileUploader" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="updateList()">
<div id="divFiles"></div>
```

Comment: its not working as we expect when i am trying to upload a new set o file it showing old list file names it self.

Comment: So your expected output is to append new file names to `filelist` and show new file names list in `output`?

Comment: yes the new file names need to get stored in the filelist and list in output

Comment: displaying in console but not html output. also when i upload 2 files first time then i am trying to one more file means. from the existing list one file got removed.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to save all files, Each time user select new files, push them into array.

```
var fileList = [];
```

in `updateList` function fill array

```
fileList.push(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var filelist = new Array();

updateList = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('fileUploader');
    var output = document.getElementById('divFiles');

    var HTML = "<table>";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        //filelist[i] = input.files.item(i).name;
        filelist.push(input.files.item(i).name);
        HTML += "<tr><td>" 
              + filelist[i] 
              + "</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button ></button></td></tr>";
    }
    HTML += "</table>";
    output.innerHTML = HTML;
    console.log(filelist);
}
```

```html
<input id="fileUploader" type="file" multiple="multiple" onchange="updateList()">
<div id="divFiles"></div>
```